# Fill and align vector with 0

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to compare two texts with their term frequencies using the similarity measure.

Imagine the following two sentences:

> text1 = "wikipedia is an internet encyclopedia supported and hosted by the non-profit wikimedia foundation".split()
>
> text2 = "wikipedia is a free encyclopedia built collaboratively using wiki software".split()

Then I use their term frequency as vectors:

```
from collections import Counter
vec_x = Counter(text1).values()
vec_y = Counter(text2).values()
```

Now I want the values to be aligned, so for example the count of "by" in vec_x coincides in the same position with the count of "by" in vec_y, and in case the word doesn't appear in any of the vectors, add 0 to the vector, so they have the same length. So, for example:

```
#vectors obtained 
#vec_x = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
#vec_y = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]

#Output expected
#vec_x = [0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
#vec_y = [1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Thanks in advance. Any help is appreciated.

Edit: Sorry for the typos

Comment: @Keozon missed the `split()` at the end, my bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Generalizing a little to handle an arbitrary number of sentences, we can align your vectors by creating a list of all the words and then iterating over the counts in that order:

```
>>> texts = [text1, text2]
>>> counts = [Counter(text) for text in texts]
>>> all_words = sorted(set().union(*counts))
>>> vecs = [[count.get(word, 0) for word in all_words] for count in counts]
>>> vecs[0]
[0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1]
>>> vecs[1]
[1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1]
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer :) Exactly what I was looking for.